# Seaborn x-axis format

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, heatmap, seaborn

After creating a Pandas dataframe, I am generating a Seaborn heatmap using the following commands:

```
# Create heatmap
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
g = sns.heatmap(df_abs, cmap='inferno', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, xticklabels='auto')
loc, labels = plt.xticks()
g.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
loc, labels = plt.yticks()
g.set_yticklabels(labels, rotation=0)
sns.set(font_scale=4)
plt.title('Spectral absorption')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [THz]')
plt.ylabel('Angle of Incidence [$^o$]')
plt.show()
```

However, my x-axis is still ugly:

[image]
 -- how can I specify the start value, end value, increment value, and make the values into integers? I've tried looking through the documentation for both `plt.xlabel`, `g.set_xticklabels`, and `sns.heatmap` options, but I'm having trouble finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`seaborn.heatmap` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

> `xticklabels`, `yticklabels` : “auto”, bool, list-like, or int, optional
>
> If True, plot the column names of the dataframe. If False, don’t plot the column names. If list-like, plot these alternate labels as the xticklabels. If an integer, use the column names but plot only every n label. If “auto”, try to densely plot non-overlapping labels.

Hence

```
sns.heatmap(..., xticklabels=5)
```

will give you 5 ticklabels. Or

```
sns.heatmap(..., xticklabels=["1","Banana","12/12/2018"])
```

will label the categories as `"1","Banana","12/12/2018"`.

If this is not what you're after, probably you wouldn't even want a seaborn heatmap at all. But rather a usual `pcolormesh` plot, which uses a numeric axis, instead of a categorical one and hence allows to set the ticks and ticklabels to your liking.